# Dúvidas em relação ao grunt

Tags: javascript, grunt

Não sou muito experiente em javascript e queria saber o que seria uma versão pra produção. Estou utilizando o [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) para concatenar e minificar minha aplicação, afim de tornar essa menor. Os arquivos gerados por esse processo (app.js, app.min.js) vão parar dentro da pasta **dist/js/**.

Então temos essa estrutura:

```
APP
  | -- dist -- js -- app.js / app.min.js
  | -- images
  | -- scripts / controllers / services / etc
  | -- bower_components / dependencias
  | -- node_modules / ...
  | -- views
```

Minha dúvida é: quando colocarmos isso em produção, jogamos a pasta APP inteira ou botamos no processo do grunt, pra ele copiar o conteudo de images, views e gerar uma versão dentro de dist, na qual seria independente dos outros recursos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao usar o `Grunt`, você está gerando o pacotes para diversos ambientes. A pasta que você coloca em produção é a `dist` a pasta App serve de ambiente de desenvolvimento, seria bom você incluir uma tarefa para enviar para a pasta dist os arquivos das images também.

**Sobre o Grunt.**

Pensa no Grunt como um automatizador de tarefas. Algumas tarefas levam tempo e podem conduzir a erros o Grunt, vai automatizar isso. No seu `Gruntfile.js` você vai definir quais tarefas e também poderá modificar e incluir outras tarefas, inclusive modificar a saída dos arquivos de produção.

Se você precisa as vezes de um pacote para testes e outros para produção, você também pode definir isso, vai do seu gosto e também de bastantes consultas a documentação do Grunt

Comment: Então, o dist deve conter todas as minhas dependencias, inclusives os scripts importados?

Comment: Exato, se você não está usando uma CDN, você deve colocar em alguma outra pasta e concatenar e minificar os arquivos e configurar o Grunt para deixar tudo em sua pasta `dist`.

Vou colocar o link de um repositório no Github, que usei o Grunt para você poder consultar. É um dos meus primeiros usos com Grunt, mas dá para ter uma ideia.

https://github.com/flpms/MQBC

Comment: Valeu a ajuda! Vou tentar ver formas de copiar os arquivos de dependencias, tipo o angularjs que ta dentro da pasta bower. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Então nesse caso você pode fazer referencia ao arquivo do Angular no seu gruntfile.

Comment: Mas nesse caso, eu teria que pra cada arquivo, referenciar manualmente, certo?

Comment: Sim. Não sei se o Angular, já providencia isso no Gruntfile.